# How do I convert units in R from °C (for temperature) and % change (for precipitation)?

Tags: r, unit-conversion

The data set is described as based on the CMIP5 model ensemble, and represents the average temperature and precipitation change expected at approximately 2.8x2.8 degrees resolution in latitude/longitude. In this case, however, the data has been scaled by cumulative CO2 emissions, which means that the numbers represent the amount of local climate change expected for each 1000 billion tonnes of carbon that we emit. This data is
described in the paper “Seasonal climate change patterns due to cumulative CO2 emissions” (available on Moodle), and contains annual and seasonal temperature and precipitation changes per unit carbon emission.

I have this question: The units of the data are currently °C (for temperature) and % change (for precipitation) per 1000 billion tonnes of carbon (C) emitted. Convert the units to per 1000 billion tonnes of CO2 (where 1 tonne of C = 3.67 tonnes of CO2). Create a map of the annual temperature and precipitation change data.

How do I convert the units and then create the maps?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Is this a homework question? (The problem statement makes it sound that way.) Homework questions *are* allowed on SO, but (like all questions) it's best if you can show that you've made some attempt to solve the problem yourself, and then say exactly where you got stuck.